# Can I do a silent install of the Java JRE without installing the Ask toolbar?

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to automate the install of a Java 7 runtime on my Windows Server.  I can make the install run silently, but the Ask toolbar seems to get installed as well.  This enrages me even more than when it prompts during the desktop install.

How can I make it stop?  And while I'm at it, is there a way to not prompt for third-party products when doing the regular updates on the desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy!  After downloading the executable installer (for example, http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7/jre-7-windows-x64.exe), open a command line with administrative privileges, go to your downloads directory, and run the executable with `/s SPONSORS=0`

For example:

```
jre-7-windows-x64.exe /s SPONSORS=0
```

This will not only run a silent installation, but it will bypass any sponsor offers.